# How do you add a delay to Jquery text display

Tags: jquery, timer

I've researched this question pretty thoroughly here and no answers have worked for me.  I am displaying text from a book one word at a time in the same exact location on the screen.  I am trying to get the loop to delay `x` milliseconds, but the words get displayed immediately.  So fast that the user only sees the last word in the sentence.

Nothing, `setTimeout`, `setInterval`, waiting for `ajaxComplete`, etc slows down the display of the words.

Even if I use `ajaxComplete` and loop the words out of Ajax, `setTimeout`, `setInterval` will not slow down the display of the words.  Very frustrating.  Your help is appreciated in advance!

Need to keep ajax async - as there are buttons for users to pause, skip ahead etc.

```
function showWord(){
    $('#thedata').html(word);
}

function getThisSentence(){
    var sentence;
    var x;
    var str = '';

    var surl = "how-data.php?choice=1&book_id=7&chap_num=1&sent_num=1";
        x = 0;                                          
        $.ajax({
            cache:false,
            async:true,
            url:surl,   
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data){
                words = data.words.split(' ');
                $.each(words,function() {
                    var time = 1500;
                    word = words[x];
                    temp - word;
                    setTimeout( function(){ showWord() }, time)
                        time += 1500;

                    x++;
                });

            } 
        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the timeout with the index to get a staggered delay, and this should be all you need

```
function getThisSentence(){
    $.ajax({
        url      : "how-data.php?choice=1&book_id=7&chap_num=1&sent_num=1",   
        dataType : "json",
        success  : function(data){
            $.each(data.words.split(' '), function(index, word) {
                setTimeout(function(){  
                    $('#thedata').html(word);
                }, 1500*index);
            });
        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: Interesting - this works.  Only problem, I need the delay to be a constant.  Can you tell me why it words with a staggered delay, but not a constant one?

Comment: @SheldonGoldberg - Now you've got me confused, if you use a constant delay all the words will appear at the same time, so what it is really you want ?

Comment: I'd like to display a ward, than delay 1 second so the reader can read the sentence.  If you don't delay, they all appear at the same time.  But if you delay same amount, like 1000 milliseconds there is no noticeable delay and all of the words appear at the same time.  For some reason,  with your staggered index, the delay becomes noticeable.

Comment: I see my original code was misleading.  I had +=1500 in timer.  I just wanted 1500.  So like reading a book smoothly one word at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Using setInterval you can setup a function to run every 1500ms:

```
success: function (data) {
    words = data.words.split(' ');
    var i = 0;
    var myVar = setInterval(function () {
        showWord(i++);
        if (i >= words.length) {
            clearInterval(myVar);
        }
    }, 1500);    
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  There is zero noticeable delay.  The answer above with a staggered delay works.  Unfortunately, I need a constant delay.